# Number Tabs in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-tabs

I like to use the <kbd>Ctrl or Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd> shorcut to jump quickly to a specific tab. Problem is: When you have a lot of tabs open it is hard to look at them and quickly know which one is tab number 7.

**Is there a way (extension possibly) to show a tab's number in its title?**
This way each tab would have a number added to its title right beside the [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). This way you could immediately tell which number you need to press to jump to a specific tab.

I use both [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29) and Firefox, so I'm accepting answers for either one (though I'd prefer both =) ).

Comment: Related: *[Make Firefox display number of tabs on close of last window?](http://superuser.com/questions/553367)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the linked extensions are gone now, probably because of the Firefox Quantum update.

Fortunately, there is a new extension called "Tab Numbering" that does the same thing:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-numbering/

Answer (score 2):

[Mouseless Browsing](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mouseless-browsing/) does this for Firefox (and does a lot more too).  I haven't found something as comprehensive for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I found [NumExt](http://numext.alouche.net/) for Firefox that numbers the tabs for you.

> NumExt numbers your tabs with no limitation on how many tabs you can
>   open. The numbering is done using simple text, adding no overload on
>   the tabs. It is therefore a very lightweight, straight forward useful
>   extension for those who wish to number their tabs. NumExt colors your
>   tab as well and does more...

Comment: It works ok, but it doesn't deal well with tab groups =/ (or whatever it's called). It also counts tabs in other groups, so I have 10 tabs open right now and they are numbered from 32 to 41.

Answer (score 0):

[Fancy Numbered Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fancy-numbered-tabs/) does the job well on Firefox up to 4.0, leaving a small footprint.

Note, it shows only tabs ##1 to 9.

[image: Fancy Numbered Tabs]