# Make Firefox display number of tabs on close of last window?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Given Firefox 18, when I use "File" -> "Close Window"
(or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>)
with another browser window open and multiple tabs in the current window, I am asked "You are about to close [some number of] tabs". However, when I do the same thing in the last open Firefox window, it asks me if I want to quit and whether to save the tabs for the next invocation, without specifying how many tabs I have open in that window.

Often, I want to get a quick count of the number of tabs open, and aborting closing the window is a quick way to get that number. But as it is, if I have only one browser window open, I need to open another browser window simply to get the question I want.

Can Firefox be configured to **display the count of the number of tabs also when closing the *last* browser window of the running instance? How?**

Comment: I fail to see how this question is a duplicate of [Number Tabs in Chrome or Firefox](http://superuser.com/q/333460/53590). That question asks how to put a tab index number on each tab for easy access using the Ctrl+Number shortcut; I am asking about finding the total count of currently open tabs in a window. The two are certainly related, but they are also quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider to use [Tab Counter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-counter/) Firefox add-on - the simplest one for the task.

Comment: That worked nicely, but I had to add it to the tab bar manually through the right-click menu -> customize (it didn't show up automatically/by default).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling glad to help) most addons do have customizable settings, no surprise here.

Comment: Indeed, but it did indicate in the description that the default was that it would be shown, so I was somewhat stumped for a while.

Answer (score -2):

The answer above is outdated and that addon no longer exists. Use this addon instead : [Open tab count resurrected](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-tab-count-resurrected/)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @RayButterworth I don't have the first clue.